# width: 100PC vs media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to develop a webpage for tablet, mobile and desktop. But I am confused what to use, `width:100%` or media queries. Which one will be most useful?

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on what you want to do, if you just want the website to react to being resized, `width: 100%` will do what you want and this is generally called a `Fluid Website`

The purpose of Media Queries are to show, hide and otherwise transform elements on a page once they meet certain stylistic criteria such as width, height, devices pixel ratio, etc. These are generally called a `Responsive Website`.

Media Queries are good for showing and hiding certain non-mobile friendly navigational items, headers and footers, etc for example if a website has a large slideshow above the fold on a desktop, this is a pretty nasty user experience for someone on an iPhone or similar device; so we could write something like the below to hide it once a size criteria is met:

```
.myAwesomeSlideshow {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
  .myAwesomeSlideshow {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

I hope this clears it up a bit for you, I would use media queries personally but either solution will work well enough for you and have equal maintainability. Do note that media queries aren't supported on < IE9 though.

Comment: Thanks Dave. if there is no navigation part and only input fields, some buttons and title of page exist on the then width:100% will do everything instead of using media queries, right?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes you'll be absolutely fine with `width: 100%`

Comment: If this is the correct answer, for new visitors to this page could you mark it as accepted please?